# Nested FILTER in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I want to perform a nested filter statement in Pig.  For Example:

**Query**:

```
select trim(udc1.drky) drky,
    trim(udc1.drsy) drsy, 
    trim(udc1.drrt) drrt,
    trim(udc1.drdl01) drld01,
    'Fixed' as AssetType
from f0005 udc1 
where trim(udc1.drsy) = '12'
and trim(udc1.drrt) = 'C2' 
and trim(udc1.drky) not in (
    select trim(drky)
    from f0005
    where trim(drsy) = '57' and trim(drrt) = 'AC'
  )
```

I need to convert the above query to a Pig script.  However, I don't know how to take the filters from the inner query and associate them with the outer query.  I can write a Pig UDF as a last option but would rather implement a solution in native Pig.

Please help me with the above issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the below is your input

Input is  as per layout of

```
drky, drsy, drtt, drld01

1,57,AC,999
2,57,AC,899
2,12,C2,799
1,12,C2,699
4,57,BC,990
5,12,C3,998
6,12,C2,997
```

As Per your query the expected output is

```
6,12,C2,997
```

In Pig You can achieve this with the help of JOINS. Pls Look into below Code

```
 records = LOAD '/user/user/inputfiles/assets.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(drky:chararray,drsy:chararray,drtt:chararray,drld01:chararray);

records_filter = FILTER records BY drsy == '57' AND drtt == 'AC';

records_each = FOREACH records_filter GENERATE drky as drky_temp;

records_join = JOIN records BY drky LEFT OUTER, records_each BY drky_temp;

records_join_filter = FILTER records_join BY drky_temp is null and drsy == '12' AND drtt == 'C2';

records_output   = FOREACH records_join_filter GENERATE drky, drsy, drtt, drld01, 'FIXED' AS asset_type;

dump records_output;
```

OutPut as Per above Pig Script

```
  6,12,C2,997,FIXED
```